# Query a table using OData filter in C#

Tags: c#, odata, azure-table-storage

How do I query a table using an OData filter in C#? Please provide some examples on the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will below documentations for **OData** :

***OData Official Documentation :***

https://www.odata.org/documentation/

***OData From Microsoft :***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/

***Youtube video about OData in WEB Api :***

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Leqt7xPTKcI